# Group data without changing query flow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

For me it's hard to explait what do I want so article's name may be unclear, but I hope I can describe it with code.

I have some data with two most important value, so let it be time `t` and value `f(t)`. It's stored in the table, for example

```
1 - 1000
2 - 1200
3 - 1100
4 - 1500
...
```

I want to plot a graph using it, and this graph should contain N points. If table has rows less than this N, then we just return this table. But if it hasn't, we should group this points, for example, `N = Count/2`, then for an example above:

```
1 - (1000+1200)/2 = 1100
2 - (1100+1500)/2 = 1300
...
```

I wrote an SQL script (it works fine for N >> Count) (MonitoringDateTime - is `t`, and ResultCount if `f(t)`)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetRequestStatisticsData]
    @ResourceTypeID bigint,        
    @DateFrom datetime,         
    @DateTo datetime,            
    @EstimatedPointCount int
AS

BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ARITHABORT ON; 


    declare @groupSize int;  
    declare @resourceCount int;

    select @resourceCount = Count(*)
    from ResourceType
    where ID & @ResourceTypeID > 0


    SELECT d.ResultCount        
          ,MonitoringDateTime = d.GeneratedOnUtc
          ,ResourceType = a.ResourceTypeID,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.GeneratedOnUtc asc) AS Row
    into #t
    FROM dbo.AgentData d
      INNER JOIN dbo.Agent a ON a.CheckID = d.CheckID
    WHERE d.EventType = 'Result' AND
          a.ResourceTypeID & @ResourceTypeID > 0 AND
          d.GeneratedOnUtc between @DateFrom AND @DateTo AND
          d.Result = 1


    select @groupSize = Count(*) / (@EstimatedPointCount * @resourceCount)
    from #t

    if @groupSize = 0 -- return all points

        select ResourceType, MonitoringDateTime, ResultCount
        from #t

    else

        select ResourceType,   CAST(AVG(CAST(#t.MonitoringDateTime AS DECIMAL( 18, 6))) AS DATETIME) MonitoringDateTime, AVG(ResultCount) ResultCount
        from #t 
        where [Row] % @groupSize = 0 
        group by ResourceType, [Row]
        order by MonitoringDateTime
END
```

, but it's doesn't work for N ~= Count, and spend a lot of time for inserts. 
[image]
This is why I wanted to use `CTE's`, but it doesn't work with `if else` statement.

So i calculated a formula for a group number (for use it in GroupBy clause), because we have

```
GroupNumber = Count < N ? Row : Row*NumberOfGroups
```

where Count - numer of rows in the table, and NumberOfGroups = Count/EstimatedPointCount

using some trivial mathematics we get a formula

```
GroupNumber = Row + (Row*Count/EstimatedPointCount - Row)*MAX(Count - Count/EstimatedPointCount,0)/(Count - Count/EstimatedPointCount)
```

but it doesn't work because of Count aggregate function:

```
Column 'dbo.AgentData.ResultCount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

My english is very bad and I know it (and i'm trying to improve it), but hope dies last, so please advice.

---

results of query

```
SELECT d.ResultCount        
          , MonitoringDateTime = d.GeneratedOnUtc
          , ResourceType = a.ResourceTypeID
    FROM dbo.AgentData d
      INNER JOIN dbo.Agent a ON a.CheckID = d.CheckID
    WHERE   d.GeneratedOnUtc between '2015-01-28' AND '2015-01-30' AND
            a.ResourceTypeID & 1376256 > 0 AND
            d.EventType = 'Result' AND   
            d.Result = 1
```

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=58A31FC352FC3D1A!6118&authkey=!AATDebemNJIgHoo&ithint=file%2ccsv

Comment: Can you put some sample data up so that I can run the query against it and we will get to work.

Comment: In essense we need to implement something like [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

Comment: Can you confirm that the rest of the code behaves like you want it to, and that you are only wanting help with the part in the `else` statement? If so, I would go with some variation of @Damien_The_Unbeliever 's answer. you only need some pseudo value to group on.

Comment: @GB I didn't try entire solution yet, but it's the best and I got some new info. So i mark it as answer, and thanks for your help, it's invaluable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using [`NTILE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) and your simple sample data at the top of your question:

```
declare @samples table (ID int, sample int)
insert into @samples (ID,sample) values
(1,1000),
(2,1200),
(3,1100),
(4,1500)

declare @results int
set @results = 2

;With grouped as (
    select *,NTILE(@results) OVER (order by ID) as nt
    from @samples
)
select nt,AVG(sample) from grouped
group by nt
```

Which produces:

```
nt                   
-------------------- -----------
1                    1100
2                    1300
```

If `@results` is changed to 4 (or any higher number) then you just get back your original result set.

Unfortunately, I don't have your full data nor can I fully understand what you're trying to do with the full stored procedure, so the above would probably need to be adapted somewhat.

Comment: NTILE is a good solution, but it is not ideal. If the number of rows in a partition is not divisible by integer_expression, this will cause groups of two sizes that differ by one member. Larger groups **come before** smaller groups in the order specified by the OVER clause. For example if the total number of rows is 53 and the number of groups is five, the first three groups will have 11 rows and the two remaining groups will have 10 rows each. Ideally (at least for me, author may think differently), larger groups would be shuffled with smaller groups evenly: `LsLsL`, not `LLLss`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but how about instead of

```
select ResourceType,   CAST(AVG(CAST(#t.MonitoringDateTime AS DECIMAL( 18, 6))) AS DATETIME) MonitoringDateTime, AVG(ResultCount) ResultCount
        from #t 
        where [Row] % @groupSize = 0 
        group by ResourceType, [Row]
        order by MonitoringDateTime
```

perhaps something like

```
select ResourceType,   CAST(AVG(CAST(#t.MonitoringDateTime AS DECIMAL( 18, 6))) AS DATETIME) MonitoringDateTime, AVG(ResultCount) ResultCount
        from #t 
        group by ResourceType, convert(int,[Row]/@groupSize)
        order by MonitoringDateTime
```

Maybe that points you in some new direction? by converting to int we are truncating everything after the decimal so Im hoping that will give you a better grouping? you might need to put your row-number over resource type for this to work?

Comment: I will come back to this after dinner :-)

Comment: yes, i know that this code picks first item from a group, but as i said this code has a lot of problem and i'm looking for a solution that dismiss them all. Thanks for help.